# Determine implicit conversion before comparing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

We have all inherited bad data models.  I have a data model where the FK constraint is going to a data type that isn't implicitly castable.  For example, I have a `VARCHAR` reference column (constraintColumn) which has an FK relationship with an `INT` parent column (constrainedColumn).

```
SELECT
  OBJECT_NAME(fk.constraint_object_id) KeyName
, t.name                               constrainedTable
, c.name                               constrainedColumn
, t2.name                              constraintTable
, c2.name                              constraintColumn
FROM
  sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk
    INNER JOIN
    sys.tables AS t ON
  fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN
    sys.columns AS c ON
  fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id
  AND
  fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    INNER JOIN
    sys.tables AS t2 ON
  fk.referenced_object_id = t2.object_id
    INNER JOIN
    sys.columns AS c2 ON
  fk.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
  AND
  fk.constraint_column_id = c2.column_id
ORDER BY
  t.name
, c.name;
```

How can I use `sys.types` or something else to determine which data types are implicitly castable?

[image]

Comment: Why not use that beautiful table from BOL that you posted? Store it as a table and away you go. (I'm not aware of any system catalogs that are going to help you here; conversion in T-SQL is more or less voodoo buried in the heart of the engine and we're lucky as it is to have this documentation.)

Comment: [Finding impliciet conversions in plan cache](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/08/finding-implicit-column-conversions-in-the-plan-cache.aspx)

Comment: @jeroen because I don't want to create a table to store data that may already exist somewhere else ;)  It would be my last resort.

Comment: Well, for fun, I cooked up a script (/0UTn4rq0 on pastebin) that just asks SQL Server to do all the conversions and records the result. Not suggesting you use this in production and it doesn't reproduce the above exactly (as not all types can be used as variables), but hey.

Comment: Consider the possibility that you're not really concerned about what is and isn't "implicitly castable" -- any reference where the source and target are not simply the same type is suspect. You might be able to simplify things by focusing on those instances regardless of convertibility (querying for those through the system catalog is definitely doable).

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right if you assume that there was thought when creating the data model.  I have CHAR(12) and VARCHAR(12) for example.  Even if the PK table is shorter, I want to match it.  What I don't want is if it can't cast implicitly.

Comment: But `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` and different lengths are easily handled (and note that while, say, `NVARCHAR(12)` is implicitly convertible to `CHAR(1)` with no complaint, and even `CHAR` to `INT` (!) you would probably still want to see it, which no table on convertibility will do for you). Can't you just cough up a list of all references, then start eliminating the obvious stuff, until you have the truly exceptional cases? Unless assuming wilful malice, the data model is likely still more sane than your most pessimistic estimates.

Comment: ...incidentally, I only now notice your question seems to contradict itself. For example, you mention that you have a `VARCHAR` column referencing an `INT` column. Well, those types *are implicitly convertible*, so consulting a list on those won't help you. If you want to know if the data is *actually in error*, you'll really have to look at the data (or rely on the fact that if the database is consistent, so will the foreign key relationships be, even if the types don't match).